# Android service is not running in onPostExecute

Tags: android

I'm creating a service for my android application and I want it to run in onPostExecute on another activity.

below is CheckStatus.class (service class)

```
public class CheckStatus extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e("service", "start");
        loop();
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("service", "stop service");
    }

    private void loop(){
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()+5*1000;
        while (System.currentTimeMillis()<endTime) {
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    wait(endTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
        Log.e("service", "Check status");
        new CheckStatusTask().execute();
    }

    private class CheckStatusTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        char check_online;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            //call url json POST method

            try {

                //Check return data status

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                check_online = '2';
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            dialog.dismiss();
            if (check_online == '1') {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "online", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "offline", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

So I try to call the service on another activity

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Intent check_status = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CheckStatus.class);
        startService(check_status);

    }
```

But this is not running.

How can I make it run (the service)?

Comment: Please can you add the logcat error report by editing the question

Comment: How long you want to run your service ?

Comment: did you add service in your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Please add following in your manifest.xml

```
<service
                android:name=".NameOfService">
 </service>
```